# Unable to upload to tmp directory

Tags: apache-2.2, php, permissions, upload

I'm trying to test out an http image upload function in PHP.  I've tried this on Apache on both OSX (locally) and Ubuntu (remotely).

In php.ini I set `upload_tmp_dir = /var/tmp/http-upload`.  Both `tmp` and `http-upload` have permissions set to `drwxrwxrwt`.

Every time I try uploading I get an error that the file does not exist in the temporary location.

Am I missing anything in my configuration?

The actual upload function is:

```
    if ($_FILES) {
        $target_path = '/assets/logos' . basename($_FILES['logo']['name']);
    }
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo 'success';
    }
    else {
        echo 'fail';
    }
```

And the specific error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/logos/1317156765-shinetsu.gif): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in upload.php on line 8 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/http-upload/php8CNWja' to '/logos/1317156765-shinetsu.gif' in upload.php on line 8 fail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect its trying to move your uploaded files to /assets/logos, vs /var. You may want to try using ./assets/logos, or getting the base dir for your site somehow.

Comment: I tried commenting out the move part completely and doesn't seem to be uploading to the tmp/http-upload directory at all.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't show up in the tmp directory when I was testing with the `move_uploaded_file()` commented out, but I just tried again this time specifying the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and leaving the `move_uploaded_file()` function intact and it worked on both!  Thanks for your help.